# How to identify newsletter clicks coming email spam checkers

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid

First of all, sorry for such a confusing title of this question, honestly I do not know how to phrase it better. Hopefully, my explanation is going to be clearer

Each day we send a daily newsletter to our subscribers that consists of 5-10 links that lead to articles on our website. We send this newsletter using Sendgrid API.

Whenever someone opens an article on our website we record that visit in an SQL table, including the time of the click and IP address

What we noticed is that we have a lot of records like this

[image: clicks]

All these clicks came from the same copy of the daily newsletter (each copy has a unique identifier passed to links)

As you can see all these visits came in a supper short span of time from various IP addresses - when I did an IP lookup all these were from

[image: MS data centre]

Obviously, the receiver's inbox is behind a firewall that checks all the links in the email before it passes on the the receiver.

So how to exclude => identify clicks coming from datacenters and distinguish them from genuine clicks?